# mongo range search use the unexpected index

Tags: mongodb, indexing

[Query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gyKbQ.jpg)

[Winning plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lu91N.jpg)

[Rejected plan](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qLPVx.jpg)

For some reason, I can't paste the code here directly, so please read it from image.

My question is that, why mongo choose the winning plan instead of the rejected plan. All the conditions in the query are covered by the index which in rejected plan, but mongo still didn't choose it.

I'm very confused about this, please help me, thanks!

Comment: Try running explain with the "allPlansExecution" option so you can compare the performance of each plan.

Comment: Thanks for your help, I tried the ‘allPlansExecution’ option but still feel confusing. From the explain, I found that the winning plan got 101 nReturned, 101 totalKeysExamined and 101 totalDocsExamined, its ExecutionTimeMillisEstimate is 164ms. However the rejected plan which use the index I expecting to be used got 25 nReturned, 101 totalKeysExamined and 25 totalDocsExamined, its ExecutionTimeMillisEstimate is 38ms. 
In my opinion, the rejected plan perform better than the winning plan. Is there something wrong in my analysis?

Comment: MongoDB runs the plans for a short test, and ranks them in order of documents returned per unit of work.  Since both plans examined 101 documents I expect the "works" field was also about the same, so the one that had 101 nreturned would have scored 4 times higher than the one that returned only 25.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.